# How to send status header without going to a new page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, xmlhttprequest

```js
function checkRegisterError() {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "http://ipaddressandport/users/register");
  xhr.onload = () => {
    console.log("tes");
    if (xhr.status === 400) {
      console.log("rip");
    }
  };

  xhr.send();
}
const signupBtn = document.querySelector(".signup-form-btn");
if (signupBtn) {  
  signupBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("ok");
    checkRegisterError();
  });
}
```

I'm using nodejs and express. So I have this applied on my register button which is also a type submit for a form with an action of /users/register. On my node I have this code which is registered to /users/register:

```js
exports.addUser = (request, respond) => {
  if (
    !request.body.firstName ||
    !request.body.lastName ||
    !request.body.email ||
    !request.body.username ||
    !request.body.password ||
    !request.body.gender ||
    !request.body.mobileNumber ||
    !request.body.address
  ) {
    respond.status(400).send("error empty input etc etc");
  } else {
    db.execute(
      "INSERT INTO users(firstName, lastName, email, username, password, gender, mobileNumber, address, profilePictureUrl) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
      [
        request.body.firstName,
        request.body.lastName,
        request.body.email,
        request.body.username,
        request.body.password,
        request.body.gender,
        request.body.mobileNumber,
        request.body.address,
        "https://www.eurogeosurveys.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/default_profile_pic.jpg",
      ]
    )
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        respond.redirect("/");
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
};
```

The problem is whenever I press register the forms goes to the route and it will be a blank page of whatever I sent, and there will be no logged output. I want to change certain element properties depending on what the message and status code is. How could I do that? Why am I getting directed to an empty page with the text I sent?

```html
<form class="sign-up-form" action="/users/register" method="POST">
                <div class="nav-name">
                    <input name="firstName" type="text" class="input first-name" placeholder="First name">
                    <input name="lastName" type="text" class="input last-name" placeholder="Last name">
                </div>
                <input name="email" type="text" class="input email" placeholder="Email">
                <input maxlength="16" name="username" type="text" class="input username" placeholder="User ID">
                <div class="password-container">
                    <input maxlength="16" name="password" type="password" class="input password" placeholder="Password">
                    <label class="toggle-password" for="toggle-password-register">
                        <i class="show-password fas fa-eye"></i>
                        <i class="hide-password fas fa-eye-slash"></i>
                    </label>
                    <input id="toggle-password-register" type="checkbox" class="toggle-password__input">
                </div>
                <input name="gender" type="text" class="input gender" placeholder="Gender">
                <input name="mobileNumber" type="text" maxlength="8" class="input mobile-number"
                    placeholder="Mobile number">
                <input name="address" type="text" class="input address" placeholder="Address">
                <button type="submit" class="form-btn signup-form-btn">Sign up</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: `.signup-form-btn` can you show this HTML element?  Is it in a HTML `<form>`?

Comment: yes it is in a html ```<form action="/users/register" method="POST">```

Comment: Ok,  but can you show the `.signup-form-btn` element

Comment: okay, I have edited my original post.

Comment: Your form and button are causing your form to submit a POST request to `/users/register` with the form data from your input elements. Since you seem like you don't want this behaviour, and instead want ur JS to take care of this, you can remove the `type="submit"` on your button, and the `action` and `method` attribute on your form to stop the form submission from occurring (and thus the page reload)

Comment: So I wouldn't need to set headers or anything? I could do an if else statement in my checkRegisterError and only change my element properties if there are empty values? Also if I wanted to post I just would have to link back to my routers by doing like  `xhr.open("POST", "/users/register");` right?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting redirected to empty page because you have written response.redirect('/') , you should check if Db operation is successful then according to that send response to user .

Comment: response.redirect only happens if all the inputs are valid(not empty) right